# Why I lost the filename value when I click the submit button

Tags: javascript, php

I have made a form to pass xml files on a server. Although when it correctly sends the file to the server, it seems that the pages reloads and the value of the file name is lost and my javascript code returns nothing.
However if I remove the line

```
    <input type="submit"  />
```

from the code below it keeps the filename in the variable x but it doesn't send the file to the server.
I want to send the file on the server and keep its name into a variable in order to use in any other javascript functions.

```
<?php
$uploads_dir='/web/stud/external/scomvs2/epicurus';

if(isset($_FILES['xml_file1'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['xml_file1']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['xml_file1']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['xml_file1']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['xml_file1']['type'];
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['xml_file1']['name'])));
    $expensions= array("xml","XML");

    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose an xml file.";
    }

    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }

    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$uploads_dir/$file_name");
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>

<html>
<body>
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="uploading"  name="xml_file1"/>
        <input type="submit"  />  
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("uploading").value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the page reloads because it must to pass a file to the server somehow, if you need it to not reload, you can use AJAX file submission. If AJAX is not an option, just echo the $file_name

Comment: Could you please direct me to AJAX file submission? I don't want just to echo the file name but to use it a javascript function that will go into the uploaded xml file, stored in a server, and pick node names etc

Answer (score 1):

You can add in our Javascript part the following:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = <?=json_encode($file_name)?>;
        document.getElementById("demo").textContent = x;
    }
</script>
```

Now when in Javascript you call that function, the *demo* element will show the file name. Note that it is better to use **textContent** instead of **innerHTML**, although with filenames you don't risk to have special characters that HTML would interpret (`<>&`).

Now you should also make sure that *$file_name* is always defined. So at the top of your PHP code, add:

```
$file_name = '';
```

Instead of injecting the file name in your Javascript code, you could also let it be injected directly in the *demo* tag, like this:

```
<p id="demo"><?=htmlspecialchars($file_name)?></p>
```

Then you don't need Javascript to fill it in, if that is all you wanted to do.